# Double not imported with decimal in R

Tags: r, csv, import

I want to import these data

```
Id_points; x; y; z; remarks  
1; 2562156.119; 1122172.393; 425.627; capteur  
2; 2562155.844; 1122172.412; 420.709;
```

I use the following code

```
S1<-read.csv2('section_raw_data.csv', header=TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".", fill=TRUE, colClasses=c('integer', 'double', 'double','double','character') )
```

The resulting dataframe is:

```
Id_points; x; y; z; remarks  
1; 2562156; 1122172; 425.627; capteur  
2; 2562155; 1122172; 420.709;
```

Does anyone have an idea why the first 2 double number are truncated to the decimal ?

Comment: @tonytonov `double` is a synonym for `numeric` in R: see `?double`.

Comment: @Roland thanks, removing comment.

Comment: Is there some way we can tag multi-dupe questions like this against an R-FAQ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Is there already a faq for this? If not, you could create one or tag one of the better dupes as r-faq.

Comment: @Roland I plead ignorance - is there a StackOverflow topic-specific FAQ?  I could reference http://cran.r-project.org/faqs.html 7, but that's not a great match (the R-FAQ pretty much assumes people comprehend the difference between storage and display).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are only rounded for printing. The internal representation is a double.

```
S1<-read.csv2(text="Id_points; x; y; z; remarks  
1; 2562156.119; 1122172.393; 425.627; capteur  
2; 2562155.844; 1122172.412; 420.709; ", 
              header=TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".", fill=TRUE, 
              colClasses=c('integer', 'double', 'double','double','character') )

sprintf("%f",S1$x)
#[1] "2562156.119000" "2562155.844000"
```

Comment: And the number of digits printed to the console can be adjusted with `options(digits=your_choice_here)`